# Mongoose findOneAndUpdate behaviour

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am updating my value in Mongo collection like so

```js
    if(potentialUpcomingMatchSlot1SaturdayArray.length === 1){
      for(let i=0; i<potentialUpcomingMatchSlot1SaturdayArray.length; i++){
          try{
            const matchEntries = await MatchRegister.findOneAndUpdate({
              $and: [{$or: [{$and: [{"Player1Name": potentialUpcomingMatchSlot1SaturdayArray[i].Player1Name}, {"Player2Name": potentialUpcomingMatchSlot1SaturdayArray[i].Player2Name}]},
                            {$and: [{"Player1Name": potentialUpcomingMatchSlot1SaturdayArray[i].Player2Name}, {"Player2Name": potentialUpcomingMatchSlot1SaturdayArray[i].Player1Name}]}]},
                {TournamentName: activeTournamentRecord.TournamentName}]
            }, {MatchDate: saturdayDate, MatchTime: matchTime0, MatchCompleted: 'Scheduled Tournament Match'}).exec()
          } catch (err) {
          const error = new HttpError(
            'Cant Find Tournament. ',
            500
          );
          return next(error);
          }
      }
    }
```

This is part of a long sequence of logic and further down stream I am doing some logic based on the values updated in mongo

```js
    let matchExistsInRecord
        for(let i=potentialUpcomingMatchSlot2SaturdayArray.length - 1; i>=0; i--){
            try {
              matchExistsInRecord = await MatchRegister.findOne({
                $and: [{$or: [{Player1Name: potentialUpcomingMatchSlot2SaturdayArray[i].Player1Name},{Player2Name: potentialUpcomingMatchSlot2SaturdayArray[i].Player2Name}]},
                  {TournamentName: activeTournamentRecord.TournamentName},
                  {MatchCompleted: {$eq: undefined}}
                  {MatchDate: {$ne: null}}
                ],
              }).exec()
            } catch (err) {
            const error = new HttpError(
              'Cant Find Tournament. ',
              500
            );
            return next(error);
            }
            console.log("this is the check to see if previous record in db is found")
            console.log(matchExistsInRecord)
            if(matchExistsInRecord){
              potentialUpcomingMatchSlot2SaturdayArray.splice(i, 1)
            }
        }
```

The key here is the MatchDate field. In my first code block I am updating the record and in the second code block I am querying the collection under the assumption that the MatchDate field will be updated.

Problem : - The query in the second code block fails because clearly the Match Date field is not udpated by the time it reaches the code block.

My understanding was that using AWAIT with findOneAndUpdate will ensure that the DB gets updated and then the rest of the code logic will flow.

Can someone please help me with this?

Schema Model as Requested :-

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const Schema = mongoose.Schema;

const matchRegisterSchema = new Schema({
  MatchDate: { type: String },
  MatchTime: { type: String },
  Player1Name: { type: String },
  Player1SeedLevel: { type: Number },
  Player1GroupNumber: { type: String },
  Player1TeamName: { type: String },
  ChallengingPlayer: { type: String },
  Player2Name: { type: String },
  Player2SeedLevel: { type: Number },
  Player2GroupNumber: { type: String },
  Player2TeamName: { type: String },
  ChallengedPlayer: { type: String },
  MatchFormat : { type: String },
  Winning_Player: { type: String },
  Losing_Player: { type: String },
  ScoreLine: { type: String },
  Game1Score: { type: String },
  Game1Winner: { type: String },
  Game2Score: { type: String },
  Game2Winner: { type: String },
  Game3Score: { type: String },
  Game3Winner: { type: String },
  Game4Score: { type: String },
  Game4Winner: { type: String },
  Game5Score: { type: String },
  Game5Winner: { type: String },
  Round_Number: { type: String },
  TournamentName: { type: String },
  TournametId: { type: String},
  TotalTournamentPointsForWinningPlayer: { type: Number },
  TotalTournamentPointsForLosingPlayer: { type: Number },
  GSMPointsForWinningPlayer: { type: Number },
  GSMPointsForLosingPlayer: { type: Number },
  PointsByRankForWinningPlayer: { type: Number },
  PointsByFDRForWinningPlayer: { type: Number },
  PointsByRankForLosingPlayer: { type: Number },
  PointsByFDRForLosingPlayer: { type: Number },
  TotalGSMPointsForWinningPlayer: { type: Number },
  TotalGSMPointsForLosingPlayer: { type: Number },
  SpecialTournamentPoints1: { type: Number },
  SpecialTournamentPoints2: { type: Number },
  SpecialTournamentPoints3: { type: Number },
  TotalTournamentPointsForWinningPlayerWithSpecialPoints: { type: Number },
  TotalTournamentPointsForLosingPlayerWithSpecialPoints: { type: Number },
  MatchCompleted: { type: String },
  RejectionReason: { type: String },
  PlaceholderField2: { type: String },
  PlaceholderField3: { type: String },
  PlaceholderField4: { type: String },
  ChallengerMonth: { type: String },
  ChallengerYear: { type: String },
  ProposedChallengeDate: { type: String },
  ProposedChallengeTime: { type: String },
  ChallengeStatus: { type: String },
  ChallengeMatchLocation: { type: String },
  ChallengeMatchFlag: { type: String },
  ScoreApprovalRequestRaisedBy: { type: String}
});


module.exports = mongoose.model('Match', matchRegisterSchema);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to pass the third parameter to `findOneAndUpdate` as `{new : true}`. If you don't do that, Mongoose will update the document, but will return the original. With `{new : true}` it will update the document and return the updated version.

```
const matchEntries = await MatchRegister.findOneAndUpdate(
  { ...filter },
  { ...update },
  { new: true }
);
```

Comment: hey man that worked..sorry I am not sure how i missed that..but appreciate the quick response :)

Comment: dude sorry, this actually didnt work, I didnt uncomment the comment for the check and ran, hence I thought it did, but it didnt. Any other suggestions please?

Comment: Can you add your schema Model to the question?

Comment: Done added the schema

Comment: Can you console.log(MatchRegister) after the update. Or check in the database if the document is really changed. Maybe the "saturdayDate" value that you are specifying is null?

Comment: hey man I did console.log() and I can clearly see that after the {new:true) the value returned has the match date and match time updated.

Comment: That means that the error is in second part. Did you copy/paste the code? Because you are missing the "," between 3rd and 4rd item in "$and". Also, does "MatchCompleted" property exists or not? If not, you should change the query to " {MatchCompleted: {$exists: false}}"

Comment: let me debug a little more and get back... I figured out that the second part is the issue...just not able to pin point....cheers man

Comment: Try to change " {MatchCompleted: {$eq: undefined}}" with "{MatchCompleted: {$exists: false}}".